# Need help setting timeout for http request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, https

I want to set the timeout value to 5 mins for the http client request call. So I am getting the value for timeout in my app.config as follows and using it to set the client request for 5 mins timeout session. But I am getting error as mentioned below. How do I fix this?

```
<add key="ClientSrvcTimeout" value="300000" />
```

I am using the above to set the http client timeout.

```
client.Timeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSrvcTimeout"]);
```

But I am getting error as "Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Timespan".
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The `client.Timeout` is a `TimeSpan` and your app setting is an integer serialized to a string.  And the integer represents milliseconds.

```
int milliseconds = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSrvcTimeout"]);
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);
```

I would suggest renaming the app settting to reflect that it is milliseconds, e.g. "ClientSrvcTimeoutMilliseconds".